# python(pycharm) numpy.load "Memory error"

Tags: python, numpy, memory, pycharm, load

I'm using python 3.5(64bit)
And I want to load and print numpy file with 6.4GB.
My friend sent to me the code I want. she success to load the data, but I coudln't see the same result.
I installed numpy 1.16.1 successfully.
I moved my file to local disk to fix this error. But it did't work.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('C:/Users/papar/Desktop/processed_endomondoHR_proper_interpolate.npy')
print(data)


 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/papar/PycharmProjects/untitled4/venv/plz.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = np.load('C:/Users/papar/Desktop/processed_endomondoHR_proper_interpolate.npy')
  File "C:\Users\papar\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 440, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\papar\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 693, in read_array
    array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory error means your array does not fit into memory.

How you deal with this depends on your situation:

- Verify the data type of your array, and try to find the best one for your purpose. For example if you are using `float64`, consider whether `float32` or even `float16` might be appropriate
- if your data is sparse, you may use sparse matrices. Search Scipy Sparse matrices. Be aware however that you may be limited on possible calculus to keep sparsity (for example computation of the covariance would result in a non sparse matrix)
- Consider if your computation can be done on a subset of the data. This is called subsampling. Maybe using subsampling you get a good enough model (this may be the case for a clustering algorithm like Kmean).

Comment: 1. I don't know the data type.. ,  I downloaded the numpy file from github  and when I put mouse cursor on the file name, scope & type are non-project-file and unknowns. when I saw my friend's result, it looks like just interger...                                                                                                                       And I tried to load the file in another code, but it returned exactly same error.                              Now I think it might be the location problem because the image of dll files have  a question mark. (I use pycharm)